# Variable substitution in docker-compose.yml file when running docker-compose with sudo

Tags: docker, environment-variables, sudo, docker-compose

I'm currently trying to use variable substitution in a docker-compse.yml file. This file contains the following:

```
jenkins:
  image: "jenkins:${JENKINS_VERSION}"
  external_links:
      - mongodb:mongo
  ports:
    - 8000:8080
```

The image below shows what happens when I try to start everything up.

[image: Docker compose variable not set]

As you can see, docker-compose shows a warning saying that the variable is not set. I suspect this is caused due to the use of sudo to start docker-compose. My setup (a Jenkins docker container which has access to docker and docker-compose via volume mounts) currently requires the use of sudo. Would it be better [to stop docker requiring sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/477554), or is there another way to fix this without changing the current setup?

Comment: try adding docker to your user group, so that you don t have to use sudo again and again.

Also logout and login again in your user group to make it working.

Comment: You could set the var in a script and then launch compose from the script passing it the var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo -E` preserve the user environment when running the command. It should do what you want.

Comment: This works! To clarify, I use the following command to make it work: `JENKINS_VERSION=123 sudo -E docker-compose up`

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with multiple variables? `JENKINS_VERSION=123 && JENKINS_TEST=456 sudo -E docker-compose up` is not working (obviously) and I don't like adding variables to a sudoers file or something like that.

Comment: Found it! `export JENKINS_VERSION=123 && export JENKINS_TEST=456 && sudo -E docker-compose up`

Comment: I think you can just leave them space delimited and it will work `JENKINS_VERSION=123 JENKINS_TEST=456 sudo -E docker-compose up`